# Как прикрепить к письму картинку?

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $width = trim($_POST['fbrush-width']);
    $height = trim($_POST['fbrush-height']);
    $areaM = trim($_POST['areaM']);
    $color = trim($_POST['fbrush-color']);
    $glue = trim($_POST['fbrush-glue']);
    $cost = trim($_POST['cost']);
    $orient = trim($_POST['orient']);
    $sizeWidthSm= trim($_POST['sizeWidthSm']);
    $sizeHeightSm = trim($_POST['sizeHeightSm']);
    $offset = trim($_POST['offset']);
    $textureId = trim($_POST['textureId']);
    $filtersMask = trim($_POST['filtersMask']);
    $costView= trim($_POST['costView']);
    $textureView = trim($_POST['textureView']);
    $stripsCountView = trim($_POST['stripsCountView']);
    $sname= trim($_POST['sname']);
    $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
    $city = trim($_POST['city']);
    $email= trim($_POST['email']);
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $comment = trim($_POST['comment']);
     $paytype = trim($_POST['paytype']);
      $paytype2 = trim($_POST['foto']);
     $textureView = trim($_POST['textureView']); 
 $file_name='5.png';    

     if ($textureId == 2) { $textureId =  "песок";} elseif ($textureId == 3) { $textureId =  "пыль";} elseif ($textureId == 4) { $textureId =  "мел";}
elseif ($textureId == 5) { $textureId =  "холст";} elseif ($textureId == 6) { $textureId =  "тонкий холст";}


    //Если ошибок нет, отправить email
    if(!isset($hasError)) {
$emailTo = 'tarasowgeorgij@yandex.ru'; //Сюда введите Ваш email

$body = "Ширина: $width \n\Высота: $height \n\Не знаю: $areaM \n\Цвет:\n $color \n\НЕ знаю:  $textureView \n\Цена $cost \n\не знаю $orient 
\n\см $sizeWidthSm \n\ширина $sizeHeightSm \n\что то $offset \n\текстуры $textureId \n\Маска $filtersMask
 \n\Цена $costView \n\Текстура2 $textureView \n\Что то $stripsCountView \n\что то $stripsCountView
\n\имя $sname \n\фамилия $fname \n\город $city \n\почта $email \n\телефон $phone \n\комментарий $comment \n\Оплата  $paytype 
"; 

$headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Поддерживаю @Daniel, так же вы можете отдельно аттачем подцепить не только картинку, но и другой файл(rar,zip, doc, xls и тд). Зависит от того, что вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 0):

Электронные письма поддерживают все те же теги html. То есть, чтобы прикрепить картинку, добавьте в `$body`:

```
<img src="...">
```